# Output result one by one for the submitted set of values

Tags: php, ajax

In my php home page, i have a form with around 10 to 60 fields. and when i submit it to "process.php" page it will process each field one by one and outputs the result. But this will output the results as whole. what i want to do is, submit the data using ajax and collect the output one by one and display it to user one bye one.

I have read jquery get, post and ajax methods. But how do i echo output one by one from the php page and each is collected by ajax and displayed it to user one by one ?

I kno that i can do ajax calls one by one(send one field and get response, then display it to user and send next field, so on). But i do not want to do like that. I want to send all fields in a single click and display output one by one.

This process.php use an API(using curl). So it may take some seconds delay.

Is it possible ?

More details:

```
$fields = $_POST['flds'];
foreach($fields as $f)
{
  // do cURL operation - API

  // print output
}
```

so output will be like:

```
output of field1
.....
output of field2
.....
output of field3
.....
etc..
```

ie, first it will display:

```
output of field1
```

after some seconds:

```
output of field1
output of field2
```

and goes like this. I donot want to send one field and get output and then second field and then output, etc. But i want to send whole fields and get output one by one.

is it possible ?

Similar: [flush() Not displaying output in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190203/flush-not-displaying-output-in-php)

What i tried for testing:

```
<?php
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);

$i = 10;
while($i>0)
{
    echo $i . '<br />';
    flush();
    sleep(1);
    $i--;
}
?>
```

but not working. Page looks like loading for some seconds and finally outputs the numbers as whole.

REASON for asking this question is, this api takes 4-11 seconds or more for a single execution !
So above 50 fields it will take about 10 minutes. even if extend max execution time of script user have to wait with that blank screen for this much time!

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide some code or insight of whatever you're trying to accomplish.  Otherwise just process the return of your API call with `setTimeout()`s, but I fail to understand why one would need such large delays.

Comment: The php page receiving the form data could respond with an array or an object in json format. The caller page could use that array/object to ouput information for every single field.

Comment: sorry for confusion. i edited question with a example. please check